# How to adjust a canvas that child with position (-1,-1) is displayed completely

Tags: wpf, xaml

NEW INFORMATION!!!
Meanwhile i have found a solution but there is a new problem.
The solution is to set the margin of the canvas in code-behind to a new object of type Thickness with top and left 1 or 2.
But the canvas is lying on a tabcontrol.
When i switch between tabs or make a mousedown on the canvas the margin is lost.

---

I'm working with VS2015 on a WPF-application and have a very curious problem.

I got in one of my WPF windows a canvas as parent for some child elements.

One of these elements is a rectangle which shall show the user the size of a DIN-A4 page.

It is added in code-behind to the children collection of the canvas.

Normally i would place that rectangle at position (0,0).

But because of some problems i have to trick and set the position to (-1,-1) like that:

```
    public static System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle GetRectangle(double top, double left, double width, double height)
    {
        var rectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, -1);
        System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, -1);
        rectangle.Width = Math.Round(GetSizeInPoint(width)) + 2;
        rectangle.Height = Math.Round(GetSizeInPoint(height));
        rectangle.StrokeThickness = 1;
        rectangle.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;

        return rectangle;
    }
```

But the result of it is that just a small part of the top and left border of the rectangle can be seen.

Do i have a chance to "move" the canvas so that the rectangle is displayed completely?

Hereby another important problematic point is that the Grid named "grdProtocolDesigner" can be serialized to XML and saved in the database.

So a complete restructuring would be a big problem.

Here the relevant part of my XAML including the canvas:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="protocolContainer"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="0">
    <ContentPresenter.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="grdProtocolDesigner"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <!--Important! The background of this panel has to be "Transparent" so that drag'n'drop-events can work.
                Otherwise the events are not fired.-->
                <Canvas x:Name="protocolDesignerPanel"
                        AllowDrop="True"
                        Visibility="{Binding DesignerPanelsVisibility}"
                        Width="2200" Height="4000"
                        MouseEnter="designerpanel_MouseEnter"
                        MouseLeave="designerpanel_MouseLeave"
                        MouseDown="designerpanel_MouseDown"
                        MouseMove="designerpanel_MouseMove"
                        MouseUp="designerPanel_MouseUp">
                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleProtocolLayout"/>
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <Canvas.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../../pictures/CanvasBackground.png"
                                    TileMode="Tile"
                                    Stretch="None"
                                    Viewport="0, 0, 10, 10"
                                    ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
                    </Canvas.Background>
                </Canvas>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPresenter.Content>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: As a note, it doesn't seem to make sense that there is a ContentPresenter (and also the top level Grid in its Content). You could directly put the ScrollViewer in place of the ContentPresenter. Besides that, loading images from relative file paths like `../../pictures/CanvasBackground.png` is odd. Better add the image file to your Visual Studio project (e.g. in a pictures folder) and load them by Resource File Pack URI, which you could write like `pictures/CanvasBackground.png` in XAML.

Comment: @Clemens: Thanks a lot. I got new information. Meanwhile i found a solution with setting the Margin of the Canvas, but when i make a mousedown the margin is lost. Do You know why?